# Display the User selected text in Text in Text area

Tags: javascript, c#

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* run on document load **/
        function disp() {
            //var text = document.getElementById('TextArea1').value;

            var text = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextArea1').value;
            //alert('a')

            if (text == null)
            {
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                var t = text;
          var t = text.substr(text.selectionStart, text.selectionEnd -text.selectionStart);
               document.getElementById('displayval').value = t;
                 alert(t)
                }
            }
  </script>
    <div>
    <input id="TextArea1" runat="server" type="text"/>
    <INPUT type="button" onclick= "disp()" visible="true" value="Show"/>
    <INPUT type="text"  id ="displayval" visible="true" />
    </div>
```

Here I am trying to display the User selected text through alert. But I want to display this data in Textarea2 through C#. How can I call this function there in C#. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#text-area2-id').val(t);
```

This will show it in text area 2 instead of an alert.

---

How can I call this function there in C#. ?
You can not. Javascript runs on client side, after server sends everything to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can call javascript function code behind using

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);